# Sharing internet connection via Bluetooth

Tags: networking, bluetooth, internet-connection, internet-sharing

I am trying to share my laptops (running windows 8) internet connection with my desktop (running windows 7). I have connected two Bluetooth devices correctly but it detects `Undefined Network` below it shows `No Internet access` any idea what to do?

Here is a screenshot of my laptops internet settings: 
[image]

Comment: I have never in 20 years working with a computer heard of using Bluetooth to share an internet connection.  **The bandwidth of Bluetooth is horrible.**

Comment: oo but now you are :)

Comment: Have you actually done this?  I have checked 3 questions on this subject, all of them, suggest a normal WiFI device as a solution.

Comment: no doubt , i did it...